# Reusing pages in multiprocessor operating systems

Tags: memory, operating-system, multiprocessing, shared-memory, paging

In the context of multiprocessor operating systems, what is meant by the following quote?

> The paging mechanisms on different processors must be coordinated to
>   enforce consistency when several processors share a page or segment
>   and to decide on page replacement.
>   The reuse of physical pages is the biggest problem of concern; that
>   is, it must be guaranteed that a physical page can no longer be
>   accessed with its old contents before the page is put to a new use.

The following section is specifically what I do not understand:

> The reuse of physical pages is the biggest problem of concern; that
>   is, it must be guaranteed that a physical page can no longer be
>   accessed with its old contents before the page is put to a new use.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this concept for a newbie.

Comment: I think the author is referring to the fact that, for security purposes, a page must be erased before it is given to a different process to prevent different processes from reading each other's memory and any sensitive information in it.

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks for the response. How can the page be given to another process if it is first erased?

Comment: You just replace the content of the page with, say, all zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have a physical page frame that has been previously mapped to a process as a logical page. That means that the process's page tables reference that page.

If, as part of the virtual memory management, the operating system takes that page frame away from the process (to give it to anther) it must ensure that the process's page tables do not reference the page frame.

Otherwise, you would have two (or more) processes reading and writing to the same page independently from each other and causing general havoc.

Your quote refers to the fact that the process of allocating and deallocating page frames becomes more complex in a multi-processor system.

One complexity not mentioned is that it is possible for multiple processes to map to the same page frame. When such a page frame is being deallocated, the page table for ALL the referencing processes most be updated to remove their references to it.